# What is the short word for NOT REPL environment?

Tags: terminology

In C/C++, you have to compile source code into executable, then run it. Or in Python, you write source code then an interpreter will execute that for you.

Is there a word for such programming environment?

Comment: IDE - Integrated Development Environment

Comment: Generally the distinction is between "compiled" and "interpreted" languages. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @CarlNorum I'm looking for the word that can describe the moment that you write the source code, then run it as a whole translation unit. It should work for both compile, and interpret languages.

Comment: Execution is I think what you want.

Comment: @NickBailey "Execution" does make sense because we can say "to execute c/c++ compiled file or Python written code". Thank you!